Command-line sqlplus does an unwanted change directory
Normally starting the command-line version of sql*plus (sqlplus.exe) would retain the current working folder, allowing a script that is stored in that same folder to be run with the @ command.
D:\Folder>sqlplus user/pwd@sid
SQL> host cd
D:\Folder
SQL> @myscript.sql
(myscript runs)

However, on some machines (perhaps those that have received some particular update), this behaviour has recently changed, such that if the current drive was something other than C:, then the current directory would be changed to C:\WINDOWS.
When I run sqlplus (from a Windows Command-Prompt window), I expect that from the SQL> prompt, that the current working directory (as displayed by a HOST CD command) would be the same folder as where I started from. Where this was not on C:, then I found that the current working directory inside sqlplus was changed to C:\WINDOWS.
D:\Folder>sqlplus user/pwd@sid
SQL> host cd
C:\WINDOWS
SQL> @myscript.sql
SP2-031: unable to open file "myscript.sql"

In order to run my script, I need to now specify an absolute path.
SQL> @D:\Folder\myscript.sql

If I have used any paths in the script, such as on a SPOOL command, these too need to be changed to provide some directory information. e.g. SPOOL log.txt would try to write to log.txt in C:\WINDOWS, rather than D:\Folder.
If I run the command host cd D: I can see that the current directory on D: has not changed, only that the current drive has been changed from D: to C:.
I should therefore be able to run the script using just the drive letter.
SQL> @D:myscript.sql
SP2-031: unable to open file "D:\myscript.sql"

Note that the error message reports that the location that sqlplus looked for the file in, was D:\ even though no backslash was supplied in the command. This feels like a bug.
However, the following form did work, by specifying '.' (meaning the current directory):
@SQL> @D:.\myscript.sql
(myscript runs)

If I start sqlplus from a C: folder (with my script in that folder), the current drive and directory remains unchanged and is not changed to C:\WINDOWS.
C:\Other>sqlplus user/pwd@sid
SQL> host cd
C:\Other
SQL> @myscript.sql
(myscript runs)

Once we exit from sqlplus, this original current directory is restored (I guess sqlplus acts as a shell to preserve the underlying environment).
So my question is, how can I run sqlplus without having my current directory changed to C:\WINDOWS (other than always running sqlplus from a C: directory)?
Has this change of behaviour (if always used to retain the current directory when starting sqlplus) come about from a recent update or patch (and if so, which one)?
Is it possible to change the current drive or directory from within sqlplus (for example doing something like host cd /D D:Folder? (I'm assuming not as the host command itself appears to run as a shell that is immediately discarded).

"Has this change of behaviour (if always used to retain the current directory when starting sqlplus) come about from a recent update or patch (and if so, which one)?" Run sqlplus -V and compare the version numbers to the behaviour and see whether there is any correlation? That is something you can do.

I have run sqlplus -V on two machines (one of those where behaviour has recently changed, and one where behaviour has not changed) and both report 'SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production'.

There must be either an environment variable or a setting in a configuration file instructing sqlplus.exe for using %SystemRoot% as current working directory instead of the directory defined by the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess according to current directory of the process starting this executable. I suggest therefore running on both PCs set >"%USERPROFILE%\EnvironmentVariables_%COMPUTERNAME%.txt" and compare the two created text files with all the variables.

The environment variables SQLPATH or ORACLE_PATH could be the source of the different behavior according to Configuring SQL*Plus and Oracle Changing Current Directory In Sql Plus.

If there is no environment variable which could be defined for SQL Plus which defines the current directory for it, compare the configuration setting files. Use free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool Process Monitor for logging all file system and registry accesses during start of sqlplus.exe and look on them. I recommend to search in the log for each occurrence of C:\WINDOWS and look next on the lines above.
